# Are there any Responsive templates for ASP.NET MVC 3/4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, responsive-design

I was searching for responsive templates for ASP.NET MVC 3/4 which one could use as a base and  then extend as per requirement.

After googling for a while, I came across these two options.

1. [Zurb foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), they also have a nuget package available [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Zurb_Foundation_MVC3) and detailed procedure explained [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/responsive-design-using-foundation-with-asp.net-mvc/).
2. [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html) - have never used it, but looks promising
3. [Kickstrap](http://ajkochanowicz.github.com/Kickstrap/)

Does any one know any more / compatible / better responsive templates that one could use with ASP.NET MVC websites ?

This would certainly makes lives of all MVC developers easier if they have a responsive template to begin with. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After a lot of searching I finally ended up using **Twitter Bootstrap** with ASP.NET MVC 4.

The installation is very easy, you just have to install [Twitter Bootstrap's nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap), which will download and add the required css, js and images for this, you can also manually install using [this](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404633/Transform-ASP-NET-MVC3-Default-Template-with-Twitt&ei=zySKUKy0GY-YiAfvmoDQAw&usg=AFQjCNFqiHsWxkxSmwl3rBUD3vrwrr1cag&sig2=6bvey__uSRUITSNXXi8Qng) tutorial.

Once set up I found twitter bootstrap very easy to use, they have extensive documentation for everything. These documetations are present at

- [Scaffolding](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html)
- [Base CSS](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html)
- [Component](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html)
- [Javascript](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html)

There are many sites such as [Bootsnip.com](http://bootsnipp.com/), which provide ready made code snippets for loginbox, register, poll forms and much more.

There are many sites that provide customised bootstrap theme to choose from, few of them I liked were [BuiltWithBootstrap.com](http://builtwithbootstrap.com/) and [Bootswatch.com](http://bootswatch.com/)

Here is one more [introductory article](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/twitter-bootstrap-101-introduction/) to using Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 7):

My totally biased opinion is choice #1 Zurb Foundation. (I wrote the article you referenced, the NuGet package, and [prototyping framework](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/rapid-prototyping,-the-mvc-working-model/))

I've been working with Foundation since it's release and I have to say it has been a pleasant experience. I have completed 6+ projects now using the framework and have yet to hit a major snag.

Also, the latest version has been released on NuGet [Foundation3_MVC4](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Foundation3_MVC4) (Foundation 3 & MVC 4)

Please feel free to browse the sites I've built using the framework on MVC:
[www.TubeTurns.com](http://www.TubeTurns.com)
[www.RasklUserMeeting.com](http://www.RasklUserMeeting.com)

Updated Single Page site demo: https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/Foundation3SinglePageRWD

Comment: FYI: The prototyping demo has cshtml templates included now https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/RapidPrototypingMVC4Examples

Answer (score 2):

I use Asp.Net and VS2012 - my sites are built with version 2.1.1 the Bootstrap framework. I don't use MVC or webforms (no Viewstate), just JQuery and HTML5, but as Bootstrap is client oriented, it should work fine with MVC. Kickstrap is pretty much the Bootstrap framework with themes - I have never used it.

Here is a link to one of my Bootstrap sites http://reactivewebdesign.net

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tryied [Neos-SDI MVC4 Template](http://www.mvctemplate.com). It's a good template to start developping in MVC 4. It provides a clean architecture and tools to create a website with good performance.

It's very simple to install since you can do it from Visual Studio.